# Populate ListView with SQLite, Images and Text from local resources

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have a ListView that will be able to show two TextViews and an ImageView per ListViewItem. I also have a SQLite Database that has the following fields, `_id`, `name`, `description`, `image`.

An example record would be as follows:
`1`,`R.string.name1`,`R.string.description1`,`R.drawable.image1`

The strings for name and description are in the `strings.xml` file, and the images needed are in the `res/drawable` folders, which would usually be referenced by `R.drawable.image_name`

I am using the SQLiteAssetHelper Library to manage the database.

I am able to get a cursor containing all the information needed, and I am able to populate the listview with the text, but when I run the app, the textviews show as `R.string.name1`, `R.string.description1`, etc. I have not yet been able to get the image to work at all.

How would I get the text to show properly (so I can have different languages in the future) and how would I get the images to show?

Here is my code so far:

**Database Helper**

```
    public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.sqlite";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public Database(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            setForcedUpgrade();
        }
        public Cursor getList() {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

            String [] sqlSelect = {"_id","name","description","image"};
            String sqlTables = "tbl_list";
            qb.setTables(sqlTables);
            Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                    null, null, null);

            c.moveToFirst();
            return c;

        }
    }
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class SQLite_List extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ListView listView1;
    private Cursor list;
    private Database db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("List");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        db = new Database(this);
        list = db.getList(); //Move this to its own thread later on

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                mods,
                new String[] {"name","description"}, //table values
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2});

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
...
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** I have written a new adapter, but the images are still not working:

```
public class SQLite_Adapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    public SQLite_Mods_Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        description.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        image.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("image","drawable","com.package"));
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:** I found a solution. The answer is posted below.

Comment: You can use `reflection` to get the values from the resource names. Then **in this case**, you can even `not use a custom row layout` and just incorporate the image inside a TextView (making it a **compound drawable**).

Comment: I will look into reflection, and I have implemented a custom row layout already, and a ViewBinder, and `new String[]{"name","description","image"}` and put the imageview id in "to" int[]. The text works in the custom layout, but the images do not show. Logcat shows invalid URI for R.drawable.image

Comment: that's where reflection comes in handy: use "drawable" for the reflected type.

Comment: @DerGolem I have edited my post with a new adapter, and I tried something to get images to work, but they just don't work at all. Would appreciate it if you could have a look. thanks

Comment: I got it, answer will be posted below soon. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @DerGolem

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this to work, Instead of using the SimpleCursorAdapter, use a custom adapter. Code can be found below.

Then you use the `getIdentifier` method to turn the name of the image or string, into an integer that can be used to `setText` on a TextView or `setImageResource` on an ImageView:

```
public class SQLite_ListView_Adapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    public SQLite_ListView_Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
       TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
       String name_string=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
       int resIdName = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name_string, "string", context.getPackageName());
       name.setText(resIdName);

       TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
       String description_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
       int resIdDescription = context.getResources().getIdentifier(description_string, "string", context.getPackageName());
       description.setText(resIdDescription);

       ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
       String image_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
       int resId=context.getResources().getIdentifier(image_string, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
       image.setImageResource(resId);
    }

}
```

So if you had the string, `R.string.name1` and you wanted that to show in the TextView, then in the name field of a record in your database, you only need `name1`
Similar idea with drawables and whatever else you might need